# Реклама Google Adsense в мобильной версии сайта

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте) Подскажите, пожалуйста, как убрать рекламу Google Adsense в мобильной версии сайта?

В шапку сайта установил фиксированное объявление Google Adsense размером 728х90. И в мобильной версии сайта из-за него возникает горизонтальная прокрутка. Поэтому я хочу исключить показ этого объявления в мобильной версии.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать, какой файл или какую строчку кода следует изменить? Сайт на WordPress. Адрес сайта - [Debaka.ru](http://debaka.ru/).

Comment: у вас же адаптивный сайт. скрывайте блок с рекламой свойством `display:none;`, начиная с желаемого разрешения экрана

Comment: alenkins, спасибо за ваш ответ) Теперь я спокоен, так как узнал от вас, что возможно сделать то, что я хочу) Только вот я не силен в коде, к сожалению... Скажите, пожалуйста, мне нужно всего лишь несколько строк дописать или удалить? Или нужно очень много сделать переделок в файлах сайта?

Comment: Скорее всего, правки потребуются только в файле темы `header.php`. Что именно изменить написала в ответе ниже

Answer (score 1):

Реклама у вас лежит, как я понимаю, вот в этом блоке

```
<div id="text-22" class="widget_text">...</div>
```

Сайт свёрстан с применением бутстрапа. Поэтому проще всего скрывать блок, используя его возможности. Добавьте блоку с рекламой классы `hidden-md`, `hidden-sm`, `hidden-xs` чтобы скрыть на небольших экранах. Т. е. должно получиться как-то так

```
<div id="text-22" class="widget_text hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs">...</div>
```

Comment: Большое, спасибо, alenkins)) На днях я попробую исправить)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте обернуть код `adsense` в условный тег `wp_is_mobile`:

```
<?php if ( ! wp_is_mobile() ) : ?>
    <!-- Тут ваш код подключения adsense -->
<?php endif; ?>
```